# Display collection value using their attributes name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display value of collection by passing their respective attribute name.

@mandates is the result of an active-record query.

@tabattributes contains array of attribute names previously selected by users.

The code below show field attributes but I want the value of these field instead.

I've tried several syntaxes but errors occurs each time.

How can I modify my code to do that?

> @mandates.map do |f|
>
> @tabattributes.each { |att| " #{att} "}
>
> end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@mandates` is a result set that contains models with attributes `a`, `b`, and `c` and `@tabattributes` is the array `%w{a b}` (i.e. you want to extract `a` and `b` from each element of `@mandates`) then:

```
a = @mandates.map { |m| m.attributes.slice(*@tabattributes) }
```

will give you an array of hashes with keys `'a'` and `'b'`. For example:

```
@tabattributes = %w{id created_at}
slices = @mandates.map { |m| m.attributes.slice(*@tabattributes) }
# slices is now like [ { 'id' => ..., 'created_at' => ... }, ... ]
```

If you only want the values and don't care about the keys then perhaps this will work for you:

```
@mandates.map { |m| m.attributes.slice(*@tabattributes).values }
```

That would give you an array-of-arrays. The first array-of-hashes would probably be easier to work with though.

If you can get at `@mandates` before accessing the database then you could slice out just the columns you're interested inside the database with something like this:

```
@mandates = Mandate.select(@tabattributes)
slices    = @mandates.map(&:attributes)
```

Comment: Thank's so much.  It's now working with @mandates.map { |m| m.attributes.slice(*@tabattributes).values }

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have an array of `elements`, and you want to have an array containing the `name` of each element, is that it ? If yes, then `array.map {|elem| elem.name}` should do it. There is a shorter form (`array.map(&:name)`) which does the same, if you're interested in how this is working, I can detail.